# Getting rid of invalid character from/in VSCODE

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, unicode, character

I am a totally new Golang developer, But I am facing some problem while using VSCODE. It's it's happening from time to time. It's giving me a lot of headache sometimes to debug my code. I am not sure how to fix this issue.
I am adding two images for reference ,

The first Image, There is an invalid character
[image: The first Image, There is an invalid character]

Then, I have opened the same file with another editor, And here is what I got

Same Code with another Editor
[image: Same Code with another Editor]

The problem is, This is happening automatically. I am not sure where the problem is. If you have a solution about how to avoid this without changing my editor , Please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is most likely not related to hidden unicode characters - but since `Go` source is UTF-8 compliant, "gremlin" characters can sneak in (typically when cut-n-pasting from the web). To catch these in `VScode` try [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have downloaded this plugin. And this solved my problem completely. I had no idea about this plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please include the source code in your questions - I know you wanted to show the syntax highlighting - but it helps users to reproduce the problem more easily.

---

Since Go source is [Unicode text encoded in UTF-8](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Source_code_representation) it is possible that non-visible "gremlin" characters can creep in - especially when cut-n-pasting from a browser formatted code. Take a look at this [example](https://go.dev/play/p/KmtfD4PV6Qk).

Since you are using `VScode` I recommend [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins) to highlight rogue characters within your source code.

---

Your [original code](https://go.dev/play/p/Aicm9cxth8s) has many issues stemming from mismatched types etc.

Fixing some of these, enables the code to compile/run:

```
func main() {
    k := 3   // int
    b := 2.5 // float64
    var g float32
    g = float32(k) * float32(b) // need type conversion to get desired float32
    fmt.Println(g)              // reference g - to avoid "g declared but not used" go vet error
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/XQCEMya-BlN

Comment: I will be glad if you just look a bit into the images. 
I can fix the codes, But and unknown invalid character coming out of nowhere. It's in the line 13. 
I couldn't paste the code as I can't really copy that character too.

Comment: Just because you can't see the rogue character doesn't mean you can't paste it. It somehow got into your editor. So you could paste it into the Go playground & share it that way.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Please forgive me for my ignorance as I didn't know that it might work. 
I will make sure to do it as you said in the future.